# Does react-native-safe-area-context works on Android 8 and below?

Tags: javascript, react-native, statusbar, android-9.0-pie, safeareaview

I tried exactly what is mentioned in [react-native-safe-area-context](https://github.com/th3rdwave/react-native-safe-area-context) 
I run the app in samsung android 9 and it was working as expected. 
But in my oppo device with android 8 insets were all 0.
I'm using react native 0.61.

This is my root component.

```
import React from 'react';
import { StatusBar, Platform } from 'react-native';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import { PersistGate } from 'redux-persist/es/integration/react';
import { SafeAreaProvider } from 'react-native-safe-area-context';

import { store, persistor } from './common/StoreBuilder';
import Routes from './routes/index';


if (Platform.OS === 'android') StatusBar.setHidden(true);

const App = () => (

<Provider store={store}>
  <PersistGate persistor={persistor}>
  <SafeAreaProvider><Routes /></SafeAreaProvider>
  </PersistGate>
</Provider>

);

export default App;
```

This is my consumer, which is immediate child of above component.

```
<SafeAreaConsumer>
    {insets => {
      return  <View style={{
        flex: 1,
        paddingTop: insets.top,
        paddingLeft: insets.left,
        paddingBottom: insets.bottom,
        paddingRight: insets.right,
      }}>
        <Router>
          <Stack key="root" hideNavBar>
            ...
          </Stack>
        </Router>
        <MessageContainer />
      </View>
    }}

  </SafeAreaConsumer>
```

Comment: Can you try it with another Android 8 or below device? If you do not have any, you can use Genymotion for that. It is working on my projects.

Comment: Was there anything additional needed ? Or did I miss any piece. Can you share your code ?

Comment: https://github.com/WrathChaos/react-native-header-search-bar

HeaderClassicSearchBar uses it :) You can check it out.

Comment: I figured out why behavior was different on two device. Here's a link to my solution: https://github.com/lata2694/RNSafeArea 
It is because of difference in android version below and above Android9.
You may have a look at the readme file.